# Java EBICS client

Tags: java, open-source, e-commerce, banking

I'm working on a Java project in which I should migrate a module based on ETBAC to EBICS. I've been searching for few days but I can't find any any example for such project.

The only available information is the official EBICS documentation.

Comment: An ad was posted yesterday to promote http://sourceforge.net/projects/ebics/files/, there may be some correlation (the other post was immediatly treated as ad)...

Answer (score 3):

Here, you can find a free EBICS  client (french version) written in Java:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ebics/

Comment: There is the same project with some modifications to allow developers to use it as a Maven project : https://github.com/cyrill62/ebics-java
(may be usefull for some Java devs)

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question a few times when researching for available ebics clients. 
We have developed an Open Source ruby implementation of EBICS: https://github.com/railslove/epics

It is a pure ruby implementation and runs also on jruby to be deployed in a java environment